# How to stop DIV from sticking to left of page when zoom in CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Scenario**

I have a banner on my site with a width of 2000px and when I zoom in the whole banner sticks to the left of that page.

**Question**

I would like it to stay where it is and if the user zooms in too much it will go off the page. Same way as [this sites banner](http://goo.gl/CYnBE)

**Example**

I have an image in the banner which is 2000px with the main part of the image in the center with a width of 1000px. If you zoom in the image moves and the center of the image goes to the right.

**Here is my live code: [Site Example](http://goo.gl/SsxDy)**

This is my CSS:

```
    #slideshow { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    left:0px;
    width: 2000px; 
    height: 400px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    float: none;
}
#slideshow img {
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align:center; 
}
#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
}
#banner {
    background: #EAEAEA;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 180px;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div id="banner">
    <div id="slideshow">
      <div><a href="#"><img src="AG/images/bulbs.png"></a></div>
      <div><img src="AG/images/cables.png"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm still learning so I thank you for any help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the position relative and add some padding in the direction where you want to shift the banner.

Comment: Thanks it works, however I have a issue with the overflow. I cant figure out?? -[Updated code](http://goo.gl/SsxDy)

Comment: What do you wanna do exactly ?

Comment: overflow: hidden; or overflow: scroll;

Comment: Its okay I sorted it out Thanks :D